# Creating a View that returns the first occurrence of a value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a view that returns the first occurrence of a value.

I have two tables

```
 First table: 
sID | dt 
12  | DateTimeValue1
12  | DateTimeValue2

second table: 
S_ID 
12
```

I want the view to join both tables and give me the first occurance of S_ID (in this case DateTimeValue1)

How can I accomplish this?

More Info: 
in table 1 I have two columns sID and dt. Values for these columns look like           this:

```
      sID: 1 dt: 2014-06-12 
      sID: 1 dt: 2014-06-13 
      sID 1 dt: 2014-06-14 etc...
```

I want to join the two tables in my view so that 
where S_ID matches sID it returns the first value (in this case 2014-06-12)

Sorry for any confusion!

Here's what I got so far:

This is what I got so far:

```
        CREATE VIEW view_name AS
        SELECT [S_ID]
        FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.[S_ID]=table2.sID;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question as written. Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: See group by and Min()

Comment: What makes that "first"? Because it has the earliest datetime *value*?

Comment: So in table 1 I have two columns sID and dt. 
Values for these columns look like this: 
sID: 1 dt: 2014-06-12 
sID: 1 dt: 2014-06-13
sID  1 dt: 2014-06-14 

etc...

Now in another table I have a column: S_ID
values for this column correspond with sID. 

I want to join the two tables in a created view and I want to return the first occurrence for sID: 1 dt: 2014-06-12

Comment: @AaronBertrand exactly!

Comment: This is what I got so far: 

CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT [S_ID]
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.[S_ID]=table2.sID;

Comment: @Stedy Updated bro. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @EdGibbs How's that man? Sorry! should have prepared it better I'm just somewhat frustrated and not thinking straight.

Comment: And this is for SQL Server? Why is it tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: [Here are four different ways](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2e9c/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66ee02/1

```
create view theview as
select 
  t1.s_id, min(dt) dt
from  
  table1 t1 inner join 
  table2 t2 on t1.s_id = t2.s_id
group by 
  t1.s_id
```

Comment: it's telling me dt is an invalid column. dt is in table2

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server you can select the first row of table1 and join it with table2 in a view like this:

```
create view view_name
as
select table1.*,table2.*
from table2 
     inner join
      (select top 1 *
       from table1
       order by table1.what_ever_field) as table1 
     on table2.id = table1.id
```

This works well if table2 has a foreign key to table1.

If they are independent tables with no foreign keys You can do this:

```
create view view_name
as
select table1.*,table2.*
from (select top 1 * from table2 order by table2.field1) as table2
     ,
      (select top 1 * from table1 order by table1.field1) as table1
```

Comment: For the first query: Why is TOP 1 ordered by id? The OP wants the first row *ordered by datetime*. Also, the self-join approach tends to not scale. For the second query: I have no idea what you're trying here, but if there are other id values aside from 12, you might be in for a big surprise.

Comment: This is a generic example. We can order by any field, I will edit my response.

Comment: Thanks just the same!

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
select t1.sID,min(t1.dt) from first_table t1, second_table t2 where  t1.sID=t2.sID group by t1.sID
```

I tried same with below code in sybase and it worked well.

```
create table #temp1
(sID int,dt date)


create table #temp2
(sID int)

insert into #temp1
select 12,getdate()

insert into #temp1
select 12,getdate()

insert into #temp1
select 12,getdate()

insert into #temp2
select 12

insert into #temp1
select 13,getdate()

insert into #temp2
select 13

insert into #temp1
select 14,getdate()

insert into #temp1
select 14,getdate()


insert into #temp2
select 14


select * from #temp1
select * from #temp2


select t1.sID,min(t1.dt) from first_table t1,
second_table t2
where t1.sID=t2.sID
group by t1.sID
```

Comment: Why are you using old-style `comma,joins` instead of proper `INNER JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Gotta say I couldn't agree more. The old style join syntax is confusing and outdated.